# Entity name not showing in solr

Tags: solr

I am new to solr. I have defined query in db-data-config and all the fields in managed-schema, but when i run solr there is nothing in Entity.

This is sql query in db-data-config file.

```
<entity name="Ticket" pk="ID" query="SELECT DISTINCT t.component_id, 
                         DATE(t.createddate) 
                         AS callLogDate, 
                         dm.dealercode, 
                         dm.name1, 
                         t.ticketnumber, 
                         ibm.ibasecustomername, 
                         ibm.contactpersonmobile1, 
                         ibm.pincode, 
                         ibm.city, 
                         divm.name1_lastname 
                         AS Division, 
                         pgm.productgroupdescription, 
                         pm.productname, 
                         mm.modeldesc, mm.modelcode, 

                          fsr.OBLIGATIONTYPE_ID, 
                          t.problemdescription 
                          AS ProblemDescription, 
                          DATE(t.createddate) 
                          AS Call_Log_Date, 
                          TIME (t.createddate) 
                          AS CallLoggingTime, 
                          CONCAT(CONCAT(MONTH(t.createddate), '-'), 
                          ( YEAR(t.createddate) )) AS 
                          CALLLOG_MMYYYY, 
                          (SELECT Max(TDS.updatedon) AS DISPATCHED_DATE_AND_TIME 
                           FROM   serveit.ticketdetails TDS 
                           WHERE  TDS.status_id = 1001 
                                  AND t.ticket_id = tds.ticket_id), 
                          (SELECT Min(TDS.updatedon) AS Response_Call_Date_And_Time 
                           FROM   serveit.ticketdetails TDS 
                           WHERE  TDS.status_id = 1042 
                                  AND t.ticket_id = tds.ticket_id), 
                          (SELECT Min(TIME(TDS.updatedon)) AS Response_Call_Time 
                           FROM   serveit.ticketdetails TDS 
                           WHERE  TDS.status_id = 1042 
                                  AND t.ticket_id = tds.ticket_id), 

                          (SELECT 
           Max(TDS.RESPONSE_SCHEDULED) AS Last_Response_Scheduled_Date_And_Time 
                           FROM   serveit.ticketdetails TDS 
                           WHERE  TDS.status_id = 1042 
                                  AND t.ticket_id = tds.ticket_id), 
                          (SELECT Max(TDS.updatedon) AS Resolved_Date_And_Time 
                           FROM   serveit.ticketdetails TDS 
                           WHERE  TDS.status_id = 1009 
                                  AND t.ticket_id = tds.ticket_id), 
                          (SELECT Max(TDS.updatedon) AS Closed_Date_And_Time 
                           FROM   serveit.ticketdetails TDS 
                           WHERE  TDS.status_id = 1014 
                                  AND t.ticket_id = tds.ticket_id), 
                          t.tat, 
                          fsr.fsrnumber, 
                          fsr.technicianname, 
                          wkm.work_type 
                          AS Worktype_code, 
                          (SELECT Sum(fa.amount) 
                           FROM   serveit.fsramountcollected fa 
                           WHERE  fa.fsr_id = FSR.fieldservicereport_id 
                           GROUP  BY fa.fsr_id) 
                          AS AMOUNT, 
                          rd.symptom,rd.DEFECT , rd.ACTIONTAKEN,  

                         dm.name1, 
                         dm.city 
                         AS Location, 
                         CONCAT(CONCAT(emp.name1, ' '), emp.name2) 
                         AS SDE_NAME, 
                         t.payout_rate 
                         AS Call_Amount, 
                         t.travel_allowance_rate 
                         AS Travel_Amount, 
                         ( t.payout_rate + t.travel_allowance_rate ) 
                         AS Total_Amount, 
                         cds.productserialnumber,t.CALL_TYPE_ID , fsr.MODEL_ID 

          FROM   serveit.ticket t 
                INNER JOIN serveit.ticketdetails td 
                        ON t.ticket_id = td.ticket_id 
                INNER JOIN serveit.dealermaster dm 
                        ON dm.dealer_id = td.dealer_id 
                INNER JOIN serveit.productmaster pm 
                        ON pm.product_id = td.product_id 
                INNER JOIN serveit.productgroupmaster pgm 
                        ON pm.productgroup_id = pgm.productgroup_id 
                INNER JOIN serveit.divisionmaster divm 
                        ON divm.division_id = pgm.SALESDIVISION_ID 

                INNER JOIN serveit.fieldservicereport fsr 
                        ON fsr.ticket_id = t.ticket_id 

                INNER JOIN serveit.employeemaster emp 
                        ON td.sde_id = emp.employee_id 
                INNER JOIN serveit.cdaufdetails cds 
                        ON cds.ticket_id = t.ticket_id 
                INNER JOIN serveit.modelmaster mm 
                       ON mm.MODEL_ID=fsr.MODEL_ID 

               INNER JOIN serveit.ibasemaster ibm 
                             ON ibm.ibase_id = t.ibase_id 
          INNER JOIN (SELECT     rds.FIELDSERVICEREPORT_ID, Max(rds.RESOLUTION_ID) as res_ID 
                     FROM    serveit.resolutiondetails rds    group by rds.FIELDSERVICEREPORT_ID) DFSR on Dfsr.FIELDSERVICEREPORT_ID = fsr.FIELDSERVICEREPORT_ID 
          INNER JOIN serveit.resolutiondetails rd    ON DFSR.res_ID = rd.RESOLUTION_ID 
                inner JOIN serveit.work_type_master wkm 
                             ON wkm.id = t.work_type_id 
          WHERE  t.call_type_id <> 30  and t.SCENARIONUMBER in ('1','2') 
                AND td.status_id = 1014;
                "/>
```

Not understanding why Entity is not showing in solr.

Answer (score 1):

That's too much *SQL Query* to be able to do anything at all. Does it return anything outside of Solr?

Can you try simplifying that query to one with a **single** field and see if that maps through. If it does not, then the issue is probably in schema definition and you can troubleshoot that. If it does, then it is probably SQL side issue and you need to slowly expand the query to see where it starts to fail.

Or, once single field works, create a temporary table with materialized result from that query and test against that first.

Comment: Actually at the second last line of the query there is a <> and it is not supported in solr. Not equals represented as != in solr. This fixes the issue.Chears